# MYSQL JDBC ERROR

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

This is a simple program where i create two tables in a database using jdbc and sql.

```
Connection con=null;
try
{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/","root","root");
try
{
Statement st=con.createStatement();
st.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ARCPAGE");
st.executeUpdate("USE ARCPAGE");
st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User(user_id integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,user_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,user_pass varchar(20) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (user_id))");
st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Usermap(user_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,role_name varchar(20) NOT NULL)");
ResultSet res=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM USER");
res.next();
ResultSet resmap=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM USERMAP WHERE USER_NAME='"+res.getString("user_name")+"'");
/*error line */ res.next();
resmap=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM USERMAP WHERE USER_NAME='"+res.getString("user_name")+"'");
}
catch(SQLException e)
{
    System.out.println("SQL ERROR");
}
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("ERROR");
}
```

on executing the code i get an "SQL ERROR" from the catch block.on further investigation i see that the error is from the /*error line*/ which i marked. what am i doing wrong???

-krishan

on e.printstacktrace()

```
java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.checkClosed(ResultSet.java:652)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.next(ResultSet.java:5942)
    at trees.TreeBean.<init>(TreeBean.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:405)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:265)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:191)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:73)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
    at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:71)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:69)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:112)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:190)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:178)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:164)
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getStringValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:61)
    at org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeMarkup(InputTextRenderer.java:86)
    at org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeEnd(InputTextRenderer.java:53)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:879)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:308)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:181)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:125)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:849)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1643)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:849)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1643)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1646)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1646)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1646)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeContents(TabViewRenderer.java:180)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeMarkup(TabViewRenderer.java:120)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeEnd(TabViewRenderer.java:61)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:879)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1650)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1646)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1646)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:389)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please call `e.printStackTrace()`in your exception handlers and paste the result here.

Comment: In your exception block, print the stack trace - e.printStackTrace() to get more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lots of stuff wrong with this code:

1. Prefer PreparedStatement to Statement.
2. Don't create SQL by concatenating Strings; bind variables with "?"
3. You don't close any of your Connection, Statement, or ResultSet assets.
4. Print the stack trace in catch blocks.  Your message is no information at all.
5. You look like you want to JOIN results from User and UserMap, but this is an inefficient (n+1) query way to do it.  Better to do a JOIN.
6. Shouldn't you create tables in one method and query in another?

I don't understand wny you have statements to create the database every time and create those tables.  Shouldn't that be done before you run these Java methods?  Your code isn't making much sense to me.

I'd write it more like this.  I didn't test it, but it does compile.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class SqlDemo {

    private static final String SELECT_USER_ROLE_SQL =
            "SELECT m.user_name, m.user_role " +
            "FROM User as u " +
            "JOIN Usermap as m" +
            "ON u.user_name = m.user_name ";

    public Map<String, String> getAllUserRoles(Connection connection) {
        Map<String, String> userRoles = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(SELECT_USER_ROLE_SQL);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                String user = rs.getString("user_name");
                String role = rs.getString("user_role");
                userRoles.put(user, role);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            close(rs);
            close(ps);
        }

        return userRoles;
    }

    private static void close(ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            if (rs != null) rs.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void close(Statement st) {
        try {
            if (st != null) st.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i didn write my ful code... jus the part i thought wud be relevant... so wat shud i do to solve tis??

Comment: Implementing my recommendations would be a good start.  No need to post more code - I've seen enough.

Comment: actualy my User table has a single column as primary key and Usermap has 2 composite columns as the key... so i dont think i can do a join tere...

Comment: I JOINed on user_name.  Your schema probably needs work too, but I don't have time.

Comment: @Krishan, I think @duffymo is right that your schema needs work to do. `USER`'s Key is not been referenced in `USERMAP` table. So if you are keeping `user_name` also as Key in `USER` table it would work for this case.

Comment: You can JOIN on user_name, but it'd be a good idea to add a UNIQUE constraint on that column.  There's no primary key on Usermap - never a good idea.  maybe you mean the composite of (user name, role) to be the PK.  Can't tell based on what you've posted.

Comment: Funny how Krishan has disappeared after being so quick to ask for "help pls".

Comment: i was just tryin out with that PreparedStatement... worked like a gem... i was so stupid tryin to get two resultsets with one statement... thnx... now il try n understand ur code... luks complex... :p

Comment: Complex?  It's far simpler than yours.  One method doing one thing well - remember that.

Comment: Then you'd better spell that out in your DDL.

Comment: it's a one-to-many relationship between user and role.  better modify my solution to return a map where the key is the user name and the value is a list of roles.  it needs to be a multi-map

Answer (score 0):

```
ResultSet res=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM USER");
res.next();
```

The USER table does not have any data. So before calling `res.next()` pelase check if it has some data like `if( res.hasNext() ){ ... }`.

**EDITED**

Proposed solution for your case.

```
ResultSet res=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM USER");
while( !res.next() )
{
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM USERMAP WHERE USER_NAME=?"
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    // put parameters
    setString( 1, res.getString('user_name') );
    ResultSet resmap=st.executeQuery();
    ....
    do work with resmap
    ....
    resmap.close();
}
res.close();
```

Better SQL can also make it easier.

We can use

```
ResultSet resmap=st.executeQuery(
              "SELECT m.* FROM USER u, USERMAP m WHERE u.user_name = m.user_name");
while( !res.next() )
{
    ...
}
resmap.close();
```

in this way you create only one ResultSet and get the desired result.

Comment: it does hav data... on executing the code from mysql command prompt i get the table

Comment: I am sorry but i am missing the point of creating DLL statement here and without inserting any thing getting the data out of it. Because there will be no data for the first time. So calling `res.next()` will give the error. Please see the proposed solution for your case. Hope you get the idea.

Comment: This is an inefficient (n+1) query.  You'll have one round trip to get all users and one for each user as written.  The "better SQL" you proposed is the JOIN that I did below in different form.

Comment: Yes @duffymo I have seen your solution after I submitted it mine. That is very detailed and good solution.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, we should print the stack trace for tracing the exceptions.
Next, as pointed by others, this probably has to do with there being no `res.next()`. So it is better to have a `resultset.hasNext()` check in if condition or while loop test if you want to go on till there is a next row/element in resultset.

Comment: the sol given by u is wrong as res.next() doesnt produce an error... it simply returns true or false... so the code wudnt go to the catch block bcoz of it...